# Run Yesod app as specific user with Keter

Tags: haskell, deployment, yesod

How can I ask **Keter** to run my **Yesod** app as a specific user?
Running as root doesn't seem very safe. In addition, my application is calling an external command that would like to run as a *non-superuser* and would like to access files created by the main app.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it's too late, but it would seem that snoyberg added support for this about a month ago with setuid (atleast if I understood correctly).

He has a sample keter-config.yaml file [1]:

```
root: .
host: "*4"
port: 80
setuid: myname
```

Hope it's the thing you were looking for! :)

[1] https://github.com/snoyberg/keter/blob/master/keter-config.yaml